# DDMS not showing list of processes on device

Tags: android, ddms

I am facing a problem with the DDMS in Eclipse (Eclipse + ADT) in order to debug my Android application directly on my device.

In the DDMS devices tab, I am able to see my device :

- Name of my device (Samsung S5...).
- Status ONLINE
- Version of the device (here 4.4.2).

Only screenshot options and capture trace are available :

[image: DDMS situation]

I have tried to use the android::debuggable="true" in my application but it is not working.

I have tried with another device (Nexus 5) and there is no difference...

Any ideas or tips to solve my problem ?

Comment: Reset your Eclipse settin via Window menu

Comment: What is the "path" of the reset setting ?

Comment: Window --> Reset Perspective

Comment: or simply restart the eclipse

Comment: are you able to deploy your apk on the device from eclipse?

Comment: @Dima Yes. Note : I am using Android maven to do it.

Comment: @MdAbdulGafur Not working

Comment: @waqaslam Not working aswell :(

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Preferences (OSX) > Android > DDMS > check Thread Updates Enabled by Default

Add Android Device view to get device pan(e) noted above

Set android:debuggable=true (two g's) in app tag as noted above

Run your app in emulator

Select device in device pane

Click the update threads button

Enjoy